# How do I prove that W is a subspace of V?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V = S$, the space of all infinite sequences of real numbers.

Let $W = \Big\{(a_i)_{i=1}^\infty : \text{ there is a real number }c\text{ with }a_i = c\text{ for all }i \geq 1\Big\}$

I already proved that the zero vector is in $W$, but I am not sure how to prove that some scalar $k$ * vector $v$ is in $W$ and vectors $v$ and vectors $u$ added together is in $W$. Would $ka_i = c$ be sufficient to prove that? Same thing for $a_i + b_i = c$

Answer (score 1):

These are constant sequences, i.e. $(1,1,1,\ldots)$

Sum them together element-wise? say $(x, x, x, \dots) + (y, y, y, \ldots)$ well then you get $(x+y, x+y, x+y, \ldots) \in W$ with consant value $x+y$ for each index.

Multiply a constant sequence $(x, x, x, \ldots)$ by a real-valued scalar (also applied element-wise)?

$k * (x, x, x, \ldots) = (kx, kx, kx, \ldots) \in W$ with constant value $kx$ for each index, and as you already noted the $0$ vector is $(0, 0, 0, \ldots) \in W$, so $W$ is a subspace of $S$.

Comment: So then for each case, would I say $c = x + y$ and $c = kx$ ?

Comment: Yes. $c$ is just some real value after all.